# SDL on blit, loses transparency and turns black

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl

For a few weeks me and my friends are working on a project. A game to be exact. And we came to a huge problem that ruins the game-play. The should be transparent part of player is black.

The MergeSurfaces function, is the blit. In itself the rects are written to the SDL_Rect, and blit is performed

```
void MergeSurfaces(SDL_Surface *From, SDL_Surface *To, int FromX, int FromY, int FromWidth, int FromLenght, int ToX, int ToY){




            SDL_Rect srcRect;    
            srcRect.x = FromX;    
            srcRect.y = FromY;
            srcRect.w = FromWidth;   
            srcRect.h = FromLenght;

            SDL_Rect dstRect;    
            dstRect.x = ToX;    
            dstRect.y = ToY;    

            SDL_BlitSurface(From, &srcRect, To, &dstRect);
        }
```

This is the player forming function.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----MAIN LOAD FUNCTION
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    void LoadPlayerGraphics(SDL_Surface* BodyID[], int PlayerHeight, int PlayerWidth, long EquipmentID[], int MovementAmountX, int MovementAmountY){
        SDL_Surface* Image;
        SDL_Surface* EquipmentColorization;
        std::string FileName;
        int ID;


        Clean(BodyID,MovementAmountX*MovementAmountY,PlayerWidth,PlayerHeight);


        for(int i = -1; i < 8; i++){
            ID = 0;
            //here we put a small exception to firstly load the player. And only then dress Him
            if(i == -1){
                FileName = "resource/images/Player/WhiteMaleBody.png";
                goto playerbody;
            }
            if(EquipmentID[i] != 0){
                GetFileNameByID(EquipmentID[i],FileName);
            playerbody:
                Image = IMG_Load(FileName.c_str());
                if(Image == NULL){
                    exit(1);
                }

                //Needed for equipment coloring. At this point we will put RGB masks in order to color the armor by it's type
                EquipmentColorization = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCALPHA, MovementAmountX*PlayerWidth, MovementAmountY*PlayerHeight, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);


                GraphicsFunctions.MergeSurfaces(Image,EquipmentColorization,0,0,MovementAmountX*PlayerWidth,MovementAmountY*PlayerHeight,0,0);

                for(int i = 0; i < MovementAmountY; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < MovementAmountX; j++){
                        ID++;   
                        //We put the graphics on and on on top. So we dress the frames. BodyID[ID] are frames by motion ID. We just fill this up.
                        GraphicsFunctions.MergeSurfaces(    EquipmentColorization,BodyID[ID],
                                                            (j * PlayerWidth),
                                                            (i * PlayerHeight),
                                                            PlayerWidth,PlayerHeight,
                                                            0,0);

                        if(BodyID[i] == NULL){
                            exit(2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The Clean function if you wonder what it does. I don't free the surfaces here yet. Since I do it at the end of program, and this is loaded once so far. So basically it is just for creating those surfaces in order to fill them up.

```
void Clean(SDL_Surface* TheSurface[], int MovementAmount, int PlayerWidth, int PlayerHeight){
        GraphicsFunctions.Setrgba();
        for(int i = 0; i <= MovementAmount; i++){
            TheSurface[i] = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCALPHA, PlayerWidth, PlayerHeight, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Next goes the Framing part, or making the character look that is moving. It is called elsewhere, so I could control the speed easily.

```
void Variate(SDL_Surface* Graphical_Output){
        GraphicsFunctions.MergeSurfaces(BodyID[MovementVariationID[MovementID][Variation]], Graphical_Output, 0, 0, PlayerWidth, PlayerHeight, 0, 0);
        Variation++;
        if(Variation == MovementVariationIn[MovementID]){
            Variation = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is the main thread control. The Main system thread, Blits and Flips to the surface what you see here.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----MAIN Thread Function (As Thread Repeat to infinity LOL)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int Player_Main(void *unused){

        GraphicsFunctions.Setrgba();
        PlayerGraphics = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCALPHA, 1024, 768, 32, GraphicsFunctions.r, GraphicsFunctions.g, GraphicsFunctions.b, GraphicsFunctions.a);
        while(!EndProgram){

            PlayerMovementGraphics::Variate(PlayerGraphics);

            SDL_Delay(200);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Of course there are improvements needed to be implemented here. But since I started working on SDL just a few weeks ago. I still have much to learn. That's basically all there is with graphics right now. So maybe you could detect why the player itself has black where it should be transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

```
SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCALPHA,
                      PlayerWidth, PlayerHeight, 
                      32, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

From the [documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_CreateRGBSurface):

> Using zeros for the RGB masks sets a default value, based on the depth.  However, using zero for the `Amask` results in an `Amask` of 0.

You'll need to specify your masks explicitly if you want an alpha channel:

```
SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCALPHA,
                      PlayerWidth, PlayerHeight, 32,
                      0xFF000000, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF );
```